# Not able to download Jars from Confluent repository in a gradle project

Tags: gradle, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have added confluent repo to the build.gradle file

```
 repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://packages.confluent.io/maven/"
        }
    }
```

But I am not able to download the dependency

```
compile("io.confluent:kafka-avro-serializer:3.2.1")
```

Comment: Is it, by chance, in a `buildscript` block?

Comment: it is outside the buildscript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i wanted it in subprojects so in the parent `build.gradle` i had to add as follows and this worked fine for me.

```
subprojects {
repositories {
  maven {
            url "https://packages.confluent.io/maven/"
        }
    }
}
```